# webscraping data from a company website with client side authentication

Tags: python-requests

I am trying to scrape data from my company website which requires a username, password and a one time password provided by the user in each session. I am able to get to the login page get the username and password but unable to get the one time password and pass it though the website to login and scrape the data.

Comment: Usually, username and password login via API would be exchanged for an **access_token** and sometimes plus a **refresh_token**. To confirm you are not getting these tokens check the server response **Authorization** header.

Comment: It's __Webscraping__ not webscrapping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `PyOTP`

It can be used to implement two-factor (2FA) or multi-factor (MFA) authentication methods in web applications and in other systems that require users to log in.

github ripo Learn more about it [pyotp](https://github.com/pyauth/pyotp)